Prove that $S^{-1}M\simeq S^{-1}A\otimes_A M$ using universal property.
Please use only universal property for tensor product and localization of modules. That being said, individual tensors/fractions will not be defined are not allowed.
Recall that the universal property of tensor product $M\times N\to M\otimes N$ states that for any $P$, the first arrow below$$\operatorname{Hom}_A(M\otimes_A N, P)\to\operatorname{Bilin}_A(M\times N,P)\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,\operatorname{Hom}_A(N,P))$$defined by composing with the universal arrow, is a bijection. The localization of $M$ at a multiplicatively closed set $S\subset A$ has the universal arrow $M\to S^{-1}M$ with the universal property that for any module $P$ such that every element of $S$ gives an automorphism $P\to P$ by left multiplication, there is a bijection $$\operatorname{Hom}_A(S^{-1}M,P)\to\operatorname{Hom}_A(M, P)$$by composing with the universal arrow $S\to S^{-1}M$.
How can I use the above two universal properties to prove that $S^{-1}M\simeq S^{-1}A\otimes_A M$? First it sufficies to prove for any module $P$ there is a bijection $$\operatorname{Hom}_A(S^{-1}M,P)\to\operatorname{Bilin}_A(S^{-1}A\times M,P)$$given by some bilinear universal arrow $S^{-1}A\times M\to S^{-1}M$. I get stuck here as I have some trouble constructing the bilinear map using the universal property of localization.

The property you mention means that $M \mapsto S^{-1} M$ is a left adjoint to the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Mod}_{S^{-1} A} \to \mathbf{Mod}_A$.
If $A \to B$ is any ring homomorphism, $M \mapsto B \otimes_A M$ provides the left adjoint to the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Mod}_B \to \mathbf{Mod}_A$. This is standard*
Left adjoints are unique up to isomorphism, and the claim is proven.
*Since you are interested in abstract category theory, you might want to look for a much more general purely categorical statement as Proposition 1.3.3 (applied to $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{Mod}_A$) in:

F. Marty. Des ouverts Zariski et des morphismes lisses en géométrie
relative. PhD thesis, Université de Toulouse, Université Toulouse
III-Paul Sabatier, 2009. Link.


Brilliant! Thank you for the reference!
